# exit 0 not terminating program

Tags: sockets, ocaml, client-server

I'm developing a client-server application in OCaml using the high-level network connection functions available in OCaml Unix library, following the steps available at https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/oreilly-book/html/book-ora187.html. These functions are:

`val open_connection : sockaddr -> in_channel * out_channel`

`val shutdown_connection : in_channel -> unit`

`val establish_server : (in_channel -> out_channel -> unit) -> sockaddr -> unit`

I'm able to successfully build the client and verifier but I cannot terminate the server using the `exit` OCaml function.

My (minimal) server code is the following:

```
let handle_service ic oc =
  try while true do
        ...
        if ... then raise Finish_interaction
      done ;
  with
  | Finish_interaction -> raise Sys.Break
  | _ -> ...

let main_server serv_fun =
  if Array.length Sys.argv < 4 then ...
  else try
      let port = int_of_string Sys.argv.(1) in
      ...
      let my_address = Unix.inet_addr_loopback in
      Unix.establish_server serv_fun (Unix.ADDR_INET(my_address, port)) 
    with
    | Sys.Break -> exit 0 (* PROGRAM DOES NOT TERMINATE *)
    | _ -> ...

let go_server () = 
  Unix.handle_unix_error main_server handle_service ;;

go_server ()
```

I can successfully catch the `Sys.Break` exception, but the `exit 0` code after catching that exception does nothing and the server just keeps running and waiting for another client connection.

OCaml documentation says the following regarding `establish_server`:

> The function Unix.establish_server never returns normally.

I don't know if this implies that I can never terminate the program without user interaction (via Ctrl + C, for example).

In a nutshell, how can I terminate my server? The client does terminate after `shutdown_connection` but the server keeps waiting for incoming connections. BTW, I'm compiling my code using OCamlbuild.

Comment: Not an OCaml expert, but `Unix.establish_server` says it is creating a new process for every connection. Are you sure you can catch `Sys.Break`? Because it would have been raised in a separate process. If you catch it inside `handle_service` and `exit 0`, you exit the subprocess, with no impact to the main process (except sending `sigchld`, ignored by default). I am somewhat suspicious about your claim that you can catch it at the point shown in your OP code - I don't think OCaml will pass exception to the parent in a forked process, no other language I know will do so.

Comment: It seems easiest to make `handle_service` send a [signal](https://ocaml.github.io/ocamlunix/signals.html) to its parent process. If all you need to do is make it shut down, just send `sigterm`, you don't even need to make a signal handler. If you need something more complex, you can use pipes to communicate between processes.

Comment: Hi @Amadan, thank you very much for your answers. I tried what you suggested but I get a ```"kill" failed: Operation not permitted``` error. Do you know any shortcut to overcome this problem?

Comment: Hi @Amadan (again), a shortcut without having the need to run the program as super user

Comment: Sending a signal to parent here should not require root, as they presumably both execute under the same user. Are you sure you have the right PID for the parent process (`Unix.getppid`) ? Also, are you doing it inside `handle_service`? To be sure, what I am trying to say, do something like `| Finish_interaction -> kill getppid sigterm` (my OCaml illiteracy may be showing) instead of raising.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation of [Unix.establish_server](https://ocaml.org/api/Unix.html):

> A new process is created for each connection

I recommend printing the process IDs (`Unix.getpid ()`) to make sure the process calling `exit` is the one you're expecting (the parent).

Another thing you can check is that the program is not stuck in the execution of an `at_exit` callback. For example, the following program enters an infinite loop during the call to `exit`:

```ml
let () =
  at_exit (fun () -> while true do () done);
  print_endline "all is well!";
  exit 0
```

(probably not the problem you're having but could be useful to future visitors)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve my problem, without having the need to send signals between processes.

I tweaked the `establish_server` function so that it doesn't create a loop that answers all incoming connections. By removing the loop, it will only answer one incoming connection, and then it simply ends its execution.

Here is the code for the new `establish_server` function:

```
let establish_server server_fun sockaddr =
  let domain = Unix.domain_of_sockaddr sockaddr in
  let sock = Unix.socket domain Unix.SOCK_STREAM 0 
  in Unix.bind sock sockaddr ;
     Unix.listen sock 3;
     (*while true do*)
     let (s, caller) = Unix.accept sock 
     in match Unix.fork() with
          0 -> if Unix.fork() <> 0 then exit 0 ; 
               let inchan = Unix.in_channel_of_descr s 
               and outchan = Unix.out_channel_of_descr s 
               in server_fun inchan outchan ;
                  close_in inchan ;
                  close_out outchan ;
                  exit 0
          | id -> Unix.close s; ignore(Unix.waitpid [] id)
(*done ;;*)
```

Removing the two commented lines gives you the original version of it.

Thanks everyone for the answers!